# How to find all possible ways to fit a pattern onto a 3 by 3 grid?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, pattern-matching

This is somewhat of a math question, but also somewhat of a coding problem, so I figured I'd post it here. I am writing in python3.

Let's suppose you have a 3 by 3 grid:

```
O O O
O O O
O O O
```

Now I have a pattern, for example `A B`. I want to find all ways to place this pattern onto the 3x3 grid. Rotation is not allowed. For this particular example all solutions would be:

```
A B O | O A B | O O O | O O O | O O O | O O O
O O O | O O O | A B O | O A B | O O O | O O O
O O O | O O O | O O O | O O O | A B O | O A B
```

The patterns may have any size from 1x2/2x1 up to 3x3. I can't quite wrap my head around formulating an algorithm that can do this. Keys such as A and B may appear 1 to 9 times and I do not know what names they have.

Comment: The way your example works it's just a loop over grid rows - height(pattern) + 1, which in turn loops over grid columns - len(pattern)  + 1

Comment: In this specific example that would work, but I might also have 2x3 or 2x2 patterns. Or even 3*3 patterns that have empty slots within them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I sketched in a comment for the original question:

```
import copy

def format(grids):
    lines = []
    for i in range(len(grids[0])):
        line = []
        for g in grids:
            line.append(" ".join(g[i]))
        lines.append(" | ".join(line))
    return "\n".join(lines)

def placement(grid, gi, gj, pattern):
    grid2 = copy.deepcopy(grid)
    for pi in range(len(pattern)):
        for pj in range(len(pattern[0])):
            grid2[gi + pi][gj + pj] = pattern[pi][pj]
    return grid2

def placements(grid, pattern):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(grid) - len(pattern) + 1):
        for j in range(len(grid[0]) - len(pattern[0]) + 1):
            results.append(placement(grid, i, j, pattern))
    return results

grid = [
        ['O'] * 3, 
        ['O'] * 3, 
        ['O'] * 3
]
pattern = [
        ['A', 'B']
]
print(format(placements(grid, pattern)))
```

and result is:

```
A B O | O A B | O O O | O O O | O O O | O O O
O O O | O O O | A B O | O A B | O O O | O O O
O O O | O O O | O O O | O O O | A B O | O A B
```

Comment: Just like my comment said `placements` iterates over each row and column where the pattern will fit.  `placement` "stamps" the pattern at a given position onto the grid.  Finally, the `format` generating the result format you showed for all the solutions.

Comment: You said the pattern could have holes.  The only thing that would change is `placement` where you only do the grid2 assignment if pattern[pi][pj] is not a hole.  It would make sense to use a magic symbol for hole but still let the pattern be a n * m matrix.